# Can we update a cloudformation stack to change kinesis delivery stream destination configuration from s3 to elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a **delivery stream** configured which push data in **s3 bucket**. Now I want to point this **delivery stream to ES endpoint**.
According to docs - `Switching between Amazon ES and other services is not supported. For an Amazon ES destination, you can only update to another Amazon ES destination.`
So what will be the easiest way to make this happen if this is not possible according to doc? I am doing this operation from cloudformation template.

Answer (score -1):

The CloudFormation [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream.html#cfn-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-s3destinationconfiguration) write that you can make the changes, but there will be some interruptions:

> If you change the delivery stream destination from an Amazon S3 destination to an Amazon ES destination, update requires **some interruptions**.

If not sure or don't want to experiment with a current setup, you should be able to easily (because you use CFN) spin up second set of S3 bucket, Firehose and ES to make some tests.

Comment: When I add "ElasticsearchDestinationUpdate" property and remove "ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration" property from template cloudformation gave me "Encountered unsupported property ElasticsearchDestinationUpdate" error

Comment: @Vivek Maybe CloudFormation docs are incorrect then. Could ask at [github](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/aws-resource-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream.md) for the docs for clarification?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your comment but I couldn't find anything related to destination update in those docs.

Comment: @Vivek I quoted the sentence from the docs: If you change the delivery stream destination from an Amazon S3 destination to an Amazon ES destination, update requires some interruptions.

Comment: Now I called update_destination api from lambda function with necessary inputs but still I got "An error occurred (InvalidArgumentException) when calling the UpdateDestination operation: Changing the destination type to or from Elasticsearch is not supported at this time."

Comment: @Vivek I'm confused now. In the question you wrote that you use CloudFormation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212788/discussion-between-vivek-and-marcin).

Comment: @Vivek Unfortunately I can't. Sorry. I will be finishing for today in just few minutes.

Comment: Yes I wrote CloudFormation but I could not able to do it. There is no property like UpdateDestination neither on AWS docs nor on Github docs. So I thought lets try by API. But still it says that it is not possible